# Jquery slideToggle with If/Else statement

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

My if/else statement doesn't work. What I need to do is change the css (margin-top) of the #Scroller-Text. It must happen when the header is clicked which triggers the $nav.slideToggle. It's for a responsive site, so I also need to make sure my code doesn't distort anything in the tablet or desktop view.

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $window = $(window),
        $nav = $('.link'),
        $button = $('header');

    $button.on('click', function (){
        $nav.slideToggle(400);

         if($(this).is(':visible')) {
             $('#Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '60');
         } else {
             $('Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '102');
         }
    });  

    function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        if (width > 600) {
            $nav.show();
        } else {
           $nav.hide();
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
    <nav>
        <ul id="mobile_active">
            <li class="link"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="#">Creative</a></li>

            <li id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="links/Logo.png"/></a></li>

            <li class="link"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <header>
        <a class="mobile_menu"></a>
    </header>
</div>

 <div class="line"></div>

<div class="container">

<div id="G">
<img src="links/Image.png"/>

<div id="Text-Scroller">
<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>Body Copy</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure it has the attr `:visible`? It might just be `visible`.

Comment: Please provide some HTML markup. It looks like you are checking "this" for visibility which is the button you are clicking. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @riotburn $.is(':visible') is the correct syntax.

Comment: @ Jered I need to check the visibility of the $nav and change the margin-top css depending on whether it's visible or not without distorting my tablet or mobile view of the website. Currently, I have changed my statement to read:

    if $nav.is(':visible') {

But so far I just get a syntax error when I try out this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got...major problems here.  I'd suggest spending a bit more time learning about responsive design and javascript.  You have a document ready function inside a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

is the same as

```
$(function()
```

And you have them nested inside each other, which does not do anything. But, you actually don't need any of that code anyway.  The functionality you want can simply be added with the following css:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .link {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

That leaves just the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $nav = $('.link'),
        $button = $('header');

    $button.on('click', function (){
        $nav.slideToggle(400);

         if($(this).is(':visible')) {
             $('#Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '60');
         } else {
             $('Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '102');
         }
    });  
});
```

Here you have a couple of problems.  For one, 'this' references the dom element that the event handler was triggered from, in this case $button.  Button is never hidden, so your if block will never be true, it seems like you want to check $nav for visiblity instead.  $nav is actually an array of elements (all the links), so you can't simply check for visibility on the array, you need to check for visibility of a single item, so you actually need $($nav[0]).is(':visible');

But, even that won't work because slideToggle is an animation, and the $nav elements won't be hidden until that animation completes, but the if block will be executed immediately, so you actually need to call your if block logic in a callback after the slideToggle completes.

Then your only remaining problems are that in the else block you forgot the '#', it needs to be $('#Text-Scroller'), and that '60' and '102' don't mean anything, that could be em, px, %, etc, I'm guessing you want '60px' and '102px', which finally gives you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $nav = $('.link'),
        $button = $('header');

    $button.click(function (){
        $nav.slideToggle(400, function() {
            if($($nav[0]).is(':visible')) {
                $('#Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '60px');
            } else {
                $('#Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '102px');
            }
        });
    });  
});
```

*But* even now I'm guessing this won't get you what you want, because the menu animates down in height, and once it's finished a huge margin appears instantly.  You could animate the margin in the opposite direction...but honestly I think that's more of a sign of an improper design.  I think you should move to a css animated solution and just set a height for the nav element.  I believe this will get you what you need and will be much simpler. Here is a JSFiddle: [JSFiddle with CSS animation](http://jsfiddle.net/9keremga/25/)

Comment: Thank you for your expert advice! I am new to Jquery and originally tried a CSS solution, but when '@media (max-width: 600px) {.link {display: none;}' caused unexpected results when I resized my browser I dismissed it. Your solution works perfectly and has helped me learn more about Jquery. I still need to animate the height of the navigation since the gap problem persists. If you feel like taking a look at it here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thwhkow7/1/. If not, thanks again, you've been a huge help.

Comment: No problem!  I think we can solve that gap problem, but then I believe the nav will just push down the content, so depends on what you want.  I'll look at it though.  The reason you had issues with the css solution initially is that you hide the .link on smaller than 600px screens, but you never show it again, so you have to set it to shown again in the regular .link css.

Comment: So, as far as the height goes, the reason you have the gap there is because the height of .nav is set.  This stops the content from being pushed down when the menu is open, which I guess I thought was the behavior you wanted.  If you don't want a gap, what do you want to happen when the menu opens?  Do you want the content to get pushed down?  Do you want the menu to sit on top of the content?  If you just want the content to get pushed down, you have to stop making the content position:relative and top: 120, and instead have it's top determined by the fact that it is under the menu.

Comment: Here's a slightly modified JSFiddle of your original example where I remove nav height and the content is simply pushed down: http://jsfiddle.net/9keremga/27/

Comment: If you want the menu to overlay the content, here is a modified jsfiddle of that: http://jsfiddle.net/9keremga/28/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, the first one was my objective, just trying to figure out what in my CSS is causing problems - the #TextScroller div is overlapping part of the navigation. I know I probably need a clear:both or change a position, I just haven't found it yet. https://jsfiddle.net/thwhkow7/3/

Comment: Sorry, reread your earlier comment more carefully. When the menu opens the content is to be pushed down. I'm going to try and rework the CSS so I can be rid of the overlap. https://jsfiddle.net/thwhkow7/4/

Comment: Ya just check that first jsfiddle then.  As long as you don't set the height of .nav, you just then need to not set the top position of the content, that is what is causing the overlap on your site.  In the jsfiddle you can see the top of the content is not set, so it's free to simply move down as the menu is expanded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91780/discussion-between-nikki-heights-and-rob-louie).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that jumps out at me is the unprefixed selector in your else:

```
$('Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '102');
```

should be

```
$('#Text-Scroller').css('margin-top', '102');
```

If the element has an ID of `Text-Scroller`

Edit: Same thing with `$button = $('header')`

Edit2: Are you intending to check the visibility of `$button` instead of `$('#Text-Scroller')`? It's current checking `$button`

Comment: Thanks, I've added the ID to the selector, but I think you have the real problem on Edit2 - I need to check the visibility of the $nav. However, when I change my statement to if($)(nav).is(':visible')) {, nothing happens.

Comment: This should work `$nav.is(':visible')`. You're going to need to read up on jQuery selectors to be able to succeed in your project. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Comment: I tried that at first, but I get a syntax error on that line. The code is if $nav.is(':visible') { with the rest being the same. Thanks for the link. I obviously need to review some details.

Comment: @Nikki_Heights The entire line should read: `if ($nav.is(':visible')) {`. You need to wrap `if` statements in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. I'm not receiving any syntax errors. Is it safe to assume that the problem is not with the code, but elsewhere? I can't imagine it'd be in my HTML (added above) and I've made sure margin-top is undefined in my CSS.